# Como chamar um método da classe no code-behind do webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

É possiível chamar um método da classe no code-behind do webforms?

Default.aspx:

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 50px">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtElemento" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Inserir Elemento"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <asp:Button ID="btnInserir" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary form-control" Text="Inserir" OnClick="btnInserir_Click" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Default.aspx.cs está funcionando assim:

```
static List<Pilha> listaElementos = new List<Pilha>();
protected void btnInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pilha pilha = new Pilha();
    pilha.Elemento = txtElemento.Text;
    listaElementos.Add(pilha);
    Session["ELEMENTOS"] = listaElementos;
}
```

Só que quero chamar o método da classe, então tentei fazer desta forma:

```
protected void btnInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pilha pilha = new Pilha();        
    pilha.Inserir(txtElemento.Text);        
}
```

Classe:

```
public class Pilha
{
    public string Elemento { get; set; }
    static List<Pilha> listaElementos = new List<Pilha>();

    public void Inserir(string elemento)
    {
        listaElementos.Add(elemento);
        Session["ELEMENTOS"] = listaElementos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer chamar o método a partir do `listaElementos` ? `listaElementos[0].Inserir(txtElemento.Text);`?

Comment: @AugustoVasques É um list que recebe vários elementos

Comment: Eu sei que é um list. É que não dá para entender sua pergunta. O que exatamente você quer?

Comment: @AugustoVasques Eu queria fazer na classe o que consigo fazer no Default.aspx.cs, queria que o Default.aspx.cs apenas chamasse o método dentro da classe, é possível fazer isso?

Comment: Sim pode fazer e tem duas opções. Uma é replicar o código dentro da classe e outra é chamar o evento `btnInserir_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);`.

Comment: Ok Rodrigo, eu não tinha notado que sua lista era estática na classe.

Comment: A classe Pilha é o elemento da Lista de Pilha então não é o correto de se fazer, o correto é a lista adicionar o elemento Pilha. Você pode guardar na sessão a lista de pilha e da sessão recuperar e adicionar, remover ou editar itens da sua Lista. Será que não é isso que deseja.?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Sim é isso mesmo que gostaria fazer, mas não estou sabendo como fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu proponha uma solução:

Classe Pilha:

```
public class Pilha
{
    public Pilha(string elemento)
    {
        Elemento = elemento;
    }
    public string Elemento { get; }
}
```

Código da página:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["ELEMENTOS"] == null)
        {
            //inicia a lista de pilha 
            Session.Add("ELEMENTOS", new List<Pilha>());
        }
        //carrega a grid com os valores
        Load_GridView();
    }
}
protected void Load_GridView()
{
    if (Session["ELEMENTOS"] != null && ((List<Pilha>)Session["ELEMENTOS"]).Count > 0)
    {
        GridViewItemsPilha.DataSource = ((List<Pilha>)Session["ELEMENTOS"]).ToList();
        GridViewItemsPilha.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void BtnInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["ELEMENTOS"] != null)
    {
        ((List<Pilha>)Session["ELEMENTOS"])?.Add(new Pilha(TxtElemento.Text));
        Load_GridView();
    }
}
```

Codigo aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div class="row" style="margin: 50px">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtElemento" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Inserir Elemento"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <asp:Button ID="BtnInserir" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary form-control" Text="Inserir" OnClick="BtnInserir_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewItemsPilha" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

basicamente isso recupera a sua lista da sessão e adicione elementos na lista e os dados são carregados em uma `GridView`, exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Era isso mesmo que estava buscando, obrigado pela ajuda.